# Android Java activity Object passing

Tags: java, android, arrays, object

I'm developing a simple application to fill a criss-cross puzzle as a project.

This is the starting screen of my puzzle.

https://s22.postimg.org/jwvo49e9d/Screenshot_20161016_121252.png

Puzzle is originally a 2d array in a separate java class which implements Serializable Interface.

```
public class puzzlearr implements Serializable{

private String[][] puzzleArr = new String[][]
                {{"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"3", "0", "4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "5", "6", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"7", "0", "0", "8", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "9"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "10", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "11", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "12", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"13", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
                {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"}};

int crossnum[] = {4, 5, 7, 10, 12, 13};
int downnum[] = {1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11};

String [] crossans ={};
String [] downans ={};

public String[][] returnpuz() {
    return puzzleArr;
}

public void printArr(){
    for (int i = 0; i < puzzleArr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < puzzleArr[i].length; j++) {
            Log.i("System.out",puzzleArr[i][j]);
        }
        Log.i("System.out","");
    }
}

public void updatearr(int num, String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < puzzleArr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < puzzleArr[i].length; j++) {

            for (int m = 0; m < downnum.length; m++) {
                if (num <= 13 && downnum[m] == num) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(puzzleArr[i][j]) == num) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) {
                            puzzleArr[i][j] = String.valueOf(word.charAt(k));
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < crossnum.length; c++) {
                if (num <= 13 &&crossnum[c] == num) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(puzzleArr[i][j]) == num) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) {
                            puzzleArr[i][j] = String.valueOf(word.charAt(k));
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

I'm creating an object of the puzzlearr class and return the array to fill it on the starting activity shown above.

There are two list views on the left and right where clues are shown. After 
I click on a one clue it will open a new xml where I put the answer for the relevant question. I will also pass the puzzlearr object where I used in starting screen.(Using serializable)

After answer is submitted and press the submit, the given answer will be going through the "Void udpdatearr(int num, String word)" method and fill up the array like a puzzle. Method is working fine without any problems. I've tested it in the netbeans.

Now the problem. After I press submit and Fill the array I will be reloading the Starting screen where array and clues are available(First image). The result I need is should be like this.

https://s16.postimg.org/4nou5056d/Screenshot_20161016_121252_Copy.png

But it will not the word I submitted and will be showing the same starting screen with only numbers in it when I reload the activity.

What's wrong in here? Please some one be kind enough to help this to solve out. My dead line is two weeks above and I need to finish this before it! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: I tried but I can't find out where it is going wrong! I'm still stuck where I can't get the filled array to my activity.

Comment: Some one please help! :(